# Use parameters to connect over ssh in jenkins pipline

Tags: jenkins, ssh, pipeline

I am trying to program a pipeline that requests a username and password as parameter to connect via ssh to a linux server.

[image: screen wit pipeline parameters]

I have searched the internet for solutions but the SSH Agent plugin only works with credentials stored in Jenkins.

Is it possible to create a credential with the parameters sent by the user that executes the pipeline or use them as credentials?

Thanks!

Comment: if you click "Change Password" in the parameters screen you can provide the wanted password. you can access the parameters, for example in a shell step, via (environment) variables ($user, $pass in your case).

Comment: yes but my question is how to use the credentials with the SSH Agent plugin or a secure way to use the credentias over ssh command. thanks!

Comment: the standard SSH Agent plugin only supports key-based authentication, not password-based authentication. how do you run ssh? what kind of actions do you intend to run?